# Software for scaling zillions of images on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, images

I always have zillions of images to scale down. I generally use Photoshop for this, but even using actions Photoshop sucks for working with batches of images.

Can you guys recommend a good app I can use on Mac OS X to scale images (specially PNGs and JPEGs) with good quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you editing them individually, or are you looking for a graphics app that can handle batching commands? For the latter (and sometimes also for the former), I like [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html). Here's their page on [Batch conversion with additional functions](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/150/batch-conversion-with-additional-functions.html).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use automator?

Comment: Always worked like a charm for me. I rarely had more than a hundred images, however I think it scales well. Automator's great for non-branching tasks.

Comment: Macworld just posted a tutorial about it to boot: http://www.macworld.com/article/153650/2010/08/automate_image_conversion.html?lsrc=rss_weblogs_mac911

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) does batch processing and runs from the command line.